# How to export spreadsheet header and last row value to csv file using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, export-to-csv, spreadsheet, google-forms

I'm new here and try to seek some expertise to help to create a google apps script.

I have a spreadsheet and want to export the header and the new added row value to csv file and save it into my local c drive and send an alert email with column B value as a subject.

eg. spreadsheets has 14 columns and I would like to export start from column 2 to csv with values like: "column2 value; column3 value; column4 value; column5 value; column6 value; .....column14 value "

Below is my description workflow :

So everytime when people filled up the value in the google forms and press submit, i will received a new row value in a google sheet.  Then i will export the header and the latest row value to csv file into my local c drive and send an alert email with column B value as a subject.

Much appreciated if some expertise can help me on this. Thank you so much. :)

[image: spreadsheet value needed highlighted in yellow]

[Excel sample.xlsx](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/481a03465a8b54a5e0d4921d13994c3d20200516143134/8523ffe180bfdd93e4bc483f4201fb5520200516143153/72c434)

Comment: This appears to be a linked sheet.  I say so only because columnA header is TimeStamp.  If that is the case then you may use an onFormSubmit().  However, since an onFormSubmit may run at times when you are not online then it will be limited to storing the new data to a location within your Google Drive.  As an alternative you might consider sending an email to yourself with the most recently received data.

Comment: Google Apps Script is not for use with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you:

We'll assume you have the spreadsheet configured as follows:

- You've a sheet for submission called **Responses**
- You've a helper sheet needed for the script called **Temp** which has
  the same headers in the first row than the Responses sheet

[image]

In the illustrated example below, you want to save as CSV file the headers (Orange) along with the last row submitted (Green)

[image]

When you access the script you'll change the following:

- The Spreadsheet **ID** of the whole document
- The ID of the tab **Temp** (numbers found after **edit#gid=**)
- The **email** address of the recipient

**Code:**

```
// Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXaTto1ktqX0XNKQ035897FGX5tV75o7wuYHiNCOqEFfI/edit#gid=1269457815
  // In this link the ID of the Spreadsheet is everything after /d/
  // which is: 1kXaTto1ktqX0XNKQ035897FGX5tV75o7wuYHiNCOqEFfI
  // THE ID of the sheet Temp would be something like: 1269457815

// ---------- Menu ----------
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('CSV File')
  .addItem('Step 1: Email CSV', 'EmailRange')
  .addItem('Step 2: Save CSV file', 'showurl')
  .addToUi();
}



// Choose how do want to export the: csv,pdf,xlsx

EXPORT_TYPE="csv";

function EmailRange() {



  // Enter Sheet ID in between ""

  var sheetId = "ID GOES HERE";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Responses");

  // You can set up the headers beforehand
  var temp = ss.getSheetByName("Temp");


  //Copy range onto Temp sheet

  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange("A"+(ss.getLastRow())+":N"+(ss.getLastRow()));

  // It will erase any previous data

  rangeToCopy.copyTo(temp.getRange(2, 1));


  // Temporarily hide the sheet

  ss.getSheetByName('Responses').hideSheet()


  //Authentification 
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

  var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ss.getId()+"/export?format="+EXPORT_TYPE;

  //Fetch URL of active spreadsheet
  var fetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);

  //Get content as blob
  var blob=fetch.getBlob(); 

  var mimetype;
  if(EXPORT_TYPE=="pdf"){
    mimetype="application/pdf";      
  }else if(EXPORT_TYPE=="csv"){
    mimetype="text/csv";    
  }else if(EXPORT_TYPE=="xlsx"){
    mimetype="application/xlsx";   
  }else{
    return;
  }

  // OP: send an alert email with column B value as a subject



    var subject = sheet.getRange("B"+(ss.getLastRow()));
  var timestamp = sheet.getRange("A"+(ss.getLastRow()));
  var Title = subject.getValues();
  var signature = timestamp.getValues();


  //Change Email Recipient underneath

  GmailApp.sendEmail('s.nabil@arrowad.sch.sa',
                     'Job ID: '+Title, 
                     'Hi there,' + '\n\n' +  'A new entry has been submitted, please find the details in the attached CSV file.'  + '\n\n' +  'Submitted on: '+signature,
                     {
                         attachments: [{
                         fileName: Title + "."+EXPORT_TYPE,
                         content: blob.getBytes(),
                         mimeType: mimetype
                      }]
    });

//Reshow Response sheet

  ss.getSheetByName('Responses').showSheet()

}

function showurl() {

  // Enter Spreadsheet ID after d/ and the TAB ID of Temp after gid=


  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('Click here <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID GOES HERE/export?format=csv&gid=TAB ID GOES HERE">My File</a> to download')
  .setWidth(250) //optional
  .setHeight(50); //optional
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Download CSV File');

}
```

**STEP 1:** Sending an email to the defined recipient in the script with the **subject** being the value of the last row in column B, and the **signature** the submission date & time, like this:

[image]

The **CSV file** will be attached to the email:

[image]

**STEP 2:** From the **CSV File Menu** which is created when opening the spreadsheet:

[image]

**Save file** to your Local desktop:

[image]

Comment: Can the csv file also send to my computer local c drive as well ? i will name the folder as "CSV file". Thank you so much and really appreciate it !!! :) this is apps script that you provided is very helpful for me.

Comment: Using a DIY method: we could use `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET ID GOES HERE/export?format=csv&gid=TAB ID GOES HERE`, which will allow you to download the Temp sheet as a CSV file. So we can create a custom menu to: Step 1 send the csv file via email, Step 2 show up a dialog box with a downloadable link. **Script has been updated** for this purpose. If this answer was useful, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much again!!! The script that you provided is very useful for me. ;)

Comment: You still haven't accepted my solution as a correct answer!!  you need to consider marking the solution that helped you as a correct answer to help anyone coming across a similar situation. (it's a tick button next to the answer)